# How to open a non-full screen page using navigator in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

As shown below:

I want to open a non-full screen page like a dialog but it is not a dialog, how can I do this, please help me, thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can use stack widget inside a statefull widget to do so.

Following Example clear your idea.

onpress of floating action button you get your foreground over background.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() {
    return new MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int change=0;

  dialog(){
    return Center(
      child: new Container(
        height: 200.0,
        width: 200.0,
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
          ),
          change==1?dialog():Container()
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              if(change==0){
                change=1;
              }else{
                change=0;
              }
            });
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```